# Is there a way to convert Expression into Variable in MOSEK

Tags: c++, optimization, convex-optimization, mosek

I have a set of constraints in the following way, yet could not formulate it properly.

[image]

In the following way, I could take the norm, but how can we get its power?

```
  Model::t M = new Model();
  auto start_ = new_array_ptr<double, 1>({-4, 0, 2});
  auto x_0 = M->variable(new_array_ptr<int,1>({3, 1}), Domain::unbounded());
  M->constraint(Expr::vstack(t->index(0), Expr::sub(x_0, start_)), Domain::inQCone());
```

If we can covert `Expr::sub(x_0, start_)` expression into a variable I could try to formulate norm followed by power, but still can't understand how to do this?

Comment: Perhaps as a [lambda function expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)?

Comment: You cannot because an expression is not in general a variable, but I don't see the reason why you would ever need to.

Comment: Of course you can make a new variable x and add a constraint x-your_expr=0. Sometimes it is useful to compress the size if your_exp has lots of nonzeros and you want to use it repeatedly in many places.